# Synchronization with many stand alone threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, resources, synchronization

my applications has a big amount of threads running at the same time. After they have finished, they have to sleep a period of time (randomly) and should be restarted.

How can they be restarted with less resources? I don't want to hold all the threads in RAM while they are sleeping because the number of threads is huge. 
Another senseless solution would be to spent every thread its own timer.

Is there any best practice to solve my problem?

Comment: If the threads are sleeping, and memory gets short, the threads stack, code, data can all be paged out.  Have you found an actual problem?

Comment: I'm using Task.Run to start these threads. But its not a problem of starting or pooling these threads. The huge number of threads is necessary. I don't want to hold them because after a while 1/3 of the threads are in a sleeping mode and I could use the resources to start new ones, because the others are doing nothing. I thought about a SortedList<DateTime,Object> and a Timer which is always initialized to the first element in the List. If the DateTime is reached the timer has to fetch the first Object. Is another Object with a smaller DateTime is added, the Timer had to be reinitialized to.

Comment: But this is a little bit too difficult for me to do this synchonisation without any mistakes.

Comment: @user3299123, *.. 1/3 of the threads are in a sleeping mode* - what does this mean, are you  using `Thread.Sleep` inside `Task.Run` lambdas? That'd be a bad idea, use async lambdas and `await Task.Delay()` instead. Perhaps, you should explain your design goals.

Comment: Why sleep at all?  If you don't have work to be done you shouldn't be using a thread...  Just spin up threads or tasks when you need to perform work, let the framework and OS manage the threads, and move on.

Comment: No, when the tasks are finished they should be restarted after a while (randomly). They should do the same work again and again, just with a timeout between the restarts. `Task.Run(()=> while(true){ DoWork(); Thread.Sleep(_random.Next(x,y)}` is bad practice

Comment: @Peter Ritchie: Thats right, but how can I do this? E.g. I have ~1000 Threads, 500 running with an object, 500 in a List/Queue with a special DateTime when the thread with this object should start again. Now, If I just want to use one timer (less resources) always pointing on the first element in the list I have to do synchronization. Every running thread can add his object with a special DateTime to this list (maybe at the first position --> timer has to init again)

Comment: @user3299123, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21714108/1768303), using `Task.Delay`.

Comment: 1000 threads? Apps don't work well with much more a few threads per core.  I would suggest using tasks when you need to run code and the framework will use thread pool to manage thread usage for you.  Anything that needs to run at a dat/etime, I'd suggest a timer or the system scheduler

Comment: Creating 1000 threads is insane. Redesign this around the concept of 'jobs', work that must be done. And then run them on only a few (~ number of cores) threads.

Comment: If you are serious about using 1000 threads, you need to start looking at a framework like Akka (which is not .NET, BTW) to support it. You are not going to get away with running that many native Windows threads.

Comment: @NateC-K - you understand what is meant by 'Sleep'?  I can easily create 5000 sleepy threads on Windows.  Effect on system - essentially zero.  The box from which I post this has 1165 threads ATM.

Comment: @PeterRitchie  Firefox: 57 threads.  Kaspersky:87 threads.  Sidebar, 46 threads.  My box is running fine, doesn't seem insane.  5000 sleeping threads in C# has no detectable effect on my system, similarly native threads.

Comment: I meant working threads.  5000 sleeping threads should not affect performance once started; but they will commit 5 GB of RAM just for stack--which will require being swapped in and out of memory.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - why would the stacks get swapped.  If the thread is sleeping, it does not run any code, so there can be no page-faults.  If the threads are on long sleeps, but occasionally do some little loop code, only the stack pages for the 'little loop code' need to be accessed when the thread runs?

Comment: Just as a little test, I moved to 32-bit and started creating sleepy threads in C#.  By reducing the stack size to 64k, I managed to create 2827 sleepy threads, (under debugger, maybe more without IDE).  They exist now as I post this.

Comment: If it's sleeping, the stack isn't needed and with 5000 threads you'd have 5gb of stacks--of course it will eventually swap them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need an STA thread for UI controls or legacy COM objects, I wouldn't create any threads directly and use [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Task.TaskFactory.StartNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. For more information, check the Task Parallel Library (TPL) tag wiki:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/task-parallel-library/info

**Updated to address the comment to the question:**

> No, when the tasks are finished they should be restarted after a while
>   (randomly). They should do the same work again and again, just with a
>   timeout between the restarts. Task.Run(()=> while(true){ DoWork();
>   Thread.Sleep(_random.Next(x,y)} is bad practice

Using `Thread.Sleep` is indeed a bad practice, especially on a pool thread. It might only be good for testing. Use an async lambda and `Task.Delay` instead:

```
var task = Task.Run(async() => 
{
    while (true) 
    {
        token.ThrowIfCanncellationRequested();

        DoPeriodicWork();

        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}, token);
```

You won't be blocking a pool thread this way, it will be returned to a pool, and the code will be continued on a another pool thread after `await` (or possibly even on the same thread, but of course you should not count on this).

Note, a nested task is created for `async` lambda here, which `Task.Run` will automatically unwraps with `Task.Unwrap`. More about this in Stephen Toub's blog post: [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to look into thread pooling. This means that you start a smaller number of threads, then keep them active and have each thread do multiple jobs, one after the other. Typically they would be pulling the jobs off of a shared queue.

The .NET platform has some built-in support for doing thread pooling.

Here is an MSDN article that describes one way to do thread pooling:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx